How show a subset of columns using Python tabulate library
I am using tabulate to quickly print to screen a list of dicts. Works great except for one small thing I can't figure out. Each dict has 10 keys and I only want to print out 5 or 6 keys. Is there a way to specify a subset of keys without explicitly by brute force interating through the list and popping the unwanted keys I don't want to show on each dict? That seems like a hack...
For example I've tried:
print(tabulate.tabulate(data, headers={"id":"id", "typeId":None, "protocol":"Name"}))

All the above does is rename the columns listed and the rest of the columns still show up
print(tabulate.tabulate(data, headers=["id", "protocol"]))

raises an exception

@tripleee How is that a duplicate? I see how it's related and could be helpful, but the question is different and the top answer doesn't seem useful for this situation, though I don't use tabulate much myself.

BTW, shoap, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

@wjandrea Fair enough; reopened.
